# Backbone: Does scoping improve performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, backbone.js

When finding inner elements in a Backbone view, do you get optimal performance by limiting the scope to `this.$el`, or does the `find()` method still have to search through the whole DOM?

Here's a stub example of what I'm talking about:

```
<!-- a bunch of other stuff -->
<div id="outer">
    <!-- a bunch of other stuff -->
    <div id="inner">foo</div>
</div>
<!-- a bunch of other stuff -->
<script>
    var myView = new MyView({el: $('#outer')}); 
</script>
```

where MyView is:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //other code

    useScoping: function() {
        var $innerElement = this.$el.find('#inner');
        $innerElement.text('bar');
    },

    noScoping: function() {
        var $innerElement = $('#inner');
        $innerElement.text('bar');
    } 
});
```

Will `useScoping()` be more efficient than `noScoping()`? I would think it would be since `this.$el` has to be cached when the object is constructed, so that the search for `'#inner'` doesn't have to cover the whole DOM when scoping is used. But I wanted to make sure. Would the same apply if we had `class="inner"` with appropriate changes in the JavaScript?

Comment: See some of the performance tests on jsperf. If you already have the element for context you should use it though, for logical reasons. http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel/43

Comment: very interesting benchmarking results. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance will vary depending on the selector used.  In the example you provided the #inner selector will lookup the element by ID which uses an internally maintained index and will *not* scan the document.  Probably also true of selection using a class.

However, other selectors that don't have corresponding native implementations *will* have their performance improved by scoping.

```
// your examples will fall back to these native implementations and
// not be impacted by scoping
document.getElementById('inner')
document.getElementsByClassName('inner')
```

Comment: Thanks. Just some further clarification on the case of using a class: Is it really true that `document.getElementsByClassName('inner')` will be called even in the case of `useScoping()`? The case I'm thinking of is when there's some instance of the class `inner` outside of `#outer`. I wonder in this case because the performance is clearly worse if you first find all `.inner` elements, then look for the ones that have `#outer` as parent as opposed to just restricting the search in the first place to `this.$el`. That would also have consequences for the way you set up your classes and id tags.

Comment: Generally speaking the scoping way is better.  It's the underlying libraries job to figure out whether or not to use the native method and then filter, or to walk the DOM.  By scoping you provide the maximum information for it to make it's decision about which is better.

Walking the DOM will be linear in the number of nodes in the DOM subtree, but the native implementation of getElementsByClassName() _probably_ runs in _constant_ time by using a pre-built index, then double checking each node will be logarithmic in the tree-size.

Use scoping, though, and let the library decide.

Answer (score 1):

> the search for '#inner' doesn't have to cover the whole DOM when scoping is used

You are correct.  The Backbone view's `this.$el` is just a proxy to the JQuery-wrapped element, and so `this.$el.find` is just the JQuery [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), which searches only the descendents, not the whole DOM.

Answer (score 1):

If your worried about rendering performance the best solution is to save a variable with the jquery selector and always use that. When the model changes use the cached jquery selector to update the dom instead of re-rendering the template.

There's a bunch more tricks to make backbone views performant. I posted a backbone view subclass I'm working on at GitHub. https://github.com/puppybits/BackboneJS-PerfView It can render a collection with 1,000,000 models at over 90FPS. There's a bunch of optimizations in there with comments if your interested.